# iOS: How to programmatically trigger enter from a textfield in a webview

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to add value to a text field in a web view using javascript. First, I add value using this code :

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('birds').value = 'username';", completionHandler:nil)
```

second I need to press `Enter` button to run next function. Here is text input's info:

```
<input type="text" name="submit" id="birds" placeholder="Write username or name and press enter" "="" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

How can I programmatically trigger enter button?

Comment: What actually happens if you are in that field and you press enter?  Triggering an enter keypress may not be the right way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the form and call submit

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

This [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) could be worth a read though, you may need to select the submit button and call the `onClick` method instead, it depends how that particular form handles sending it's data.

Comment: I tried this and `.click()` but it doesn't do anything!

Comment: Did you update the form name to match the one on the website